GRIDJS: How to retrieve data from rows I select
I am using grid.js along with its selector plugin to make the user select a specific row or rows in the table.
A working example of the script is shown below.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/gridjs/dist/theme/mermaid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="table"></div>
    <button id="btn">Clicca</button>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gridjs@6.1.1/dist/gridjs.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gridjs@6.1.1/plugins/selection/dist/selection.umd.js"></script>
    <script>
        let grid = new gridjs.Grid({
            pagination: true,
            columns: [{
                    id: 'select',
                    name: 'Select',
                    plugin: {
                        component: gridjs.plugins.selection.RowSelection
                    }
                },
                'Name', 'Language', 'Released At', 'Artist'
            ],
            server: {
                url: 'https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?q=Inspiring',
                then: data => data.data.map(card => [card.name, card.lang, card.released_at, card.artist])
            }
        }).render(document.getElementById("table"));
        

        document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", function() {
            let selectedIds = grid.config.store.state.rowSelection.rowIds;
            let key = Array.from(grid.config.pipeline.cache.keys())[2];
            let tableData = grid.config.pipeline.cache;

            for (let i = 0; i < selectedIds.length; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < tableData.length; j++) {
                    if (selectedIds[i] == tableData[j].id) {
                        console.log('Match: ', selectedIds[i], tableData[j].cells[1].data, tableData[j].cells[2]
                            .data)
                    };
                };
            };
        })
    </script>

</body>

</html>



Once I have selected the rows via checkbox and clicked on the button, I want it to print, for example in console, the data of the rows I have selected, (so for example Name, Released At and Artist).
I tried to use the example below, but it is not working for me.
Can someone help me solve this or show me a simpler solution?
